# Firebase Phone Authentication with Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate users using firebase phone authentication system in Unity but when I try to follow the documentation of firebase in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone), I got error. Here is the code that I write:

```
public void sendSms()
{
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    phoneNumber = "+905555555555";
    uint phoneAuthTimeoutMs = 10000;
    PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
    provider.VerifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneAuthTimeoutMs,null,
        verificationCompleted: (credential) => {

        },
        verificationFailed: (error) => {

        },
        codeSent: (id, token) => {
            MyText.text = "SMS Has been sent " + id;
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (id) => {

        });
    MyText.text += "HMM";
}
```

But, it says "cannot resolve symbol codeAutoRetrievalTimeout". When I remove codeAutoRetrievalTimeout parameter, this time my IDE says "redundant name identifier" for codeSent, codeAutoRetrievalTimeout and verificationCompleted parts.

Here some screenshoots from my IDE about errors:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're talking about "Your IDE" but you never name it, nor its version. We can guess it's Rider but, it's not specified.

Comment: Yes its Rider. Its not just about my IDE, Unity Editor also gives same error. When I remove "**codeAutoRetrievalTimeout**" part this time gives no error but like I said Rider says "redundant identifier". If I run the program, I get "HMM" text but no SMS comes to my phone.

Comment: The second screenshot shows a warning and not an error. Have you enabled Phone Auth in your Firebase console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have *codeAutoRetrievalTime**o**ut* (lower case vowel).

Just change it to: `codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut` and the symbol will be found.

Comment: I got this error too. It comes from trying to go through Google docs and blind copy pasting.